# Looking for 1995 - 2005 website about a fantasy horde sort of like World of Warcraft but different

Tags: story-identification, online-resources

I'm looking for information regarding either a website or the works it was based on. I believe it had green text on a black background. "Horde" was a part of the name, I believe "the horde". It was a description of a unified "evil" humanoid horde, with separate entries for each fantasy race, including orcs, goblins, lizardfolk, and gremlins, among others.

One of the pages struck me at the time as being very similar to how Malcolm X described the formation of white people in his autobiography - it described humans as being originally the weakest members of the horde, made through interbreeding some of the other Horde races.

I believe I viewed the webpage on the Netscape browser. The time I viewed it would have been between 1995 and about 2005. Not *World of Warcraft* - I see the similarity, but they don't have the gremlin race, among other differences.